# Dynamically resize UITextView height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a static UITableViewCell that contains a UITextView (that dynamically gets resized based on the content it has,) and a UIView.

The cell's height dynamically changes based on the height of the textView and the view.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    [self textViewFitToContent:textView];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self scrollToLocation:textView];

    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewFitToContent:(UITextView *)textView
{
    textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}

- (void)scrollToLocation: (UITextView *)textView
{
    UIView *parentView = textView.superview;
    while (![parentView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        parentView = parentView.superview;
    }
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)parentView];
    [myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int padding = 48;

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        return 163;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        return textView1.frame.size.height + self.view1.frame.size.height + padding;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
       return textView2.frame.size.height + self.view2.frame.size.height + padding;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2) {
        return textView3.frame.size.height + self.view3.frame.size.height + padding;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 3){
        return textView4.frame.size.height + self.view4.frame.size.height + padding;
    }

    return 44;
}
```

**Problem**

The problem is, when I type in the first textView (it happens to every letter I type,) all other textView's height becomes smaller. If I type in any other textViews, (not the first one,) the first textViews height becomes bigger, and all other textViews height becomes smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Give each textView a tag. If they're in TableViewCells...make the indexPath.row the tag for each textView. In your UITextViewDelegate methods. Use an IF ELSE and do something like

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (textView.tag == 1) {
        [self textViewFitToContent:textView];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [self scrollToLocation:textView];
    }
    if (textView.tag == 2) {
        [self textViewFitToContent:textView];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [self scrollToLocation:textView];
    }
    if (textView.tag == 3) {
        [self textViewFitToContent:textView];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        [self scrollToLocation:textView];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How does that help anything?

Comment: @MikeRally your delegate methods...when you're doing something to "textView" you're doing something to all the textViews. If you specify which textView you want (by a tag) you'll get one textView to change at a time.

Comment: I just did if (textView == textView1) {...} for each textView, and the same thing happened

Comment: which method did you put that in?

Comment: textView shouldChangeTextInRange

Comment: First - assign tags to your textViews like so in where in you initialized them (viewDidLoad or wherever) and set the tag property. (example: `textView1.tag = 1`).  Try implementing exactly what I just edited my answer to. Like literally copy and paste it lol. (textView == textView1) is not the same thing as using tags

Comment: This problem is probably because of the different indexPaths in your UITableViewController. You made to define which index path your textView is in and change the size of the textView at the index path